# Centering UIBarButtonItem Plain in toolbar vertically

Tags: ios, swift2, uikit

dI have a uitoolbar that has two buttons, First one is a System Button item Camera, second is a System item flixable space, and third is a Plain Button with text. However, when the toolbar comes up, the first button is centered but the Plain button is not.

[image]

Any idea on how to change the right button to center vertically?
This is the code on setting up the toolbar:

```
    let sendButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "test", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(MyClass.test(_:)))
    let toolBarItems = [UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Camera, target: self, action: nil),
                        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil),
                        sendButton]
```

Comment: It might be something else interrupting  , this code does bring the test button in the middle of view controllers bottom toolbar .

Comment: Not sure what you are saying. This is a simple UI Toolbar.

Comment: What I am saying is I have tried your code as it is except for the action in sendButton . I took a normal view controller and added its outlet it does work the intended way , shows test in the middle, There isn't any errors in your constraints right? , it should not affect but check that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code i tried .

```
import UIKit




class ViewController2 : UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var mytoolbar: UIToolbar!
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad();

    let sendButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "test", style: .Plain, target: self, action: nil)
    let toolBarItems = [UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Camera, target: self, action: nil),
                        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil),
                        sendButton]
    mytoolbar.items = toolBarItems
}




}
```

**Edit :** I'm using the below code to create the uitoolbar programmatically.

```
 let mytoolbar = UIToolbar.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0  , y: 0, width:self.view.frame.size.width, height: 44))
        mytoolbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        let sendButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "test", style: .Plain, target: self, action: nil)
        let toolBarItems = [UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Camera, target: self, action: nil),
                            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil),
                            sendButton]
       mytoolbar.items = toolBarItems

    self.view.addSubview(mytoolbar)
```

Hope this helps now
Here are the results: [image]
It is centered i guess . Can you show me your code to add UIToolbar ?

Comment: So im actually doing this programatically. No StoryBoards. I actually managed to work around this using a UIButton and adding that to the UIBarButtonItem. Not sure why .Plain doesnt work out of the box when i do this programatically

Comment: You mean you created the uitoolbar too programatically if yes tell me i'll try that . and you are saying the style plain doesn't work out for you

Comment: yes i created it programatically. The picture i posted is the result i get :/.. Thanks for trying this out @Sourav!